# How to prevent calling ng-drop-success on click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a *div* like this:

```
<div ng-drop="$ctrl.activateDropArea" ng-drop-success="$ctrl.onDropComplete($data,$event)">
```

But *onDropComplete* is called even I just click on the draggable element inside the *div*. Can I prevent calling *onDropComplete* on click or recognize when it's real drop and when just a click?

Comment: You may need to use on-drag-start event to initialize some condition on start and check for the condition inside ng-drop-success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `ng-drag-start` and `ng-drag-success` in a combined format. i.e, set a flag inside the `ng-drag-start` event and check for that particular flag inside `ng-drag-success` and reset it. If the flag is not set that means the drag start has not happened, hence that is a click event. You can find a sample implementation in [this plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/yzEKxGmXXp93Dvf1IazG?p=preview)